# PHP Error, Image resizing

Tags: php

I'm trying to resize images before i upload them to server (aka upload file named "upload") and found a tutorial for php resizing images at http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/.I tried to integrate it with my upload function but the image does not change. What can i do to fix it ?
I use php 5.3 and HeidiSQL.

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$parts = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($parts);   
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
$mesaj= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
$nume= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if (file_exists("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
$mesaj= $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else{ $image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$image->resizeToWidth(150);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$mesaj= "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO imagini (nume) VALUES ('$nume')"); 
} 
} 
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Poza</label><input type="file" name="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Adauga imagine" class="buton_imagine" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                          "../upload/" . $image);`

`$image` is your Object you need to change `$image` to `$_FILES['file']['name']`